# return first match given threshold value

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014

The following code returns more than one match:

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Thresholds') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Thresholds

    CREATE TABLE #Thresholds(
        [Id] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [Threshold] [FLOAT] NOT NULL
    )
    INSERT INTO #Thresholds ([Threshold]) 
    SELECT 0.076923 UNION 
    SELECT 0.153846 UNION
    SELECT 0.230769 UNION
    SELECT 0.307692 UNION
    SELECT 0.384615 UNION
    SELECT 0.461538 UNION
    SELECT 0.538461 UNION
    SELECT 0.615384 UNION
    SELECT 0.692307 UNION
    SELECT 0.76923 UNION
    SELECT 0.846153 UNION
    SELECT 0.923076 UNION
    SELECT 1

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DataToBeJoined') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #DataToBeJoined

    CREATE TABLE #DataToBeJoined(
        [Value] [FLOAT] NOT NULL
    )
    INSERT INTO #DataToBeJoined ([Value]) 
    SELECT 0.25 UNION ALL
    SELECT 0.5 UNION ALL
SELECT 0.5 UNION ALL
    SELECT 0.1

SELECT 
    * 
FROM #DataToBeJoined AS a
INNER JOIN #Thresholds AS b ON a.Value >= b.Threshold
```

As follows:

```
Value   Id  Threshold
0.1     1   0.076923
0.25    1   0.076923
0.25    2   0.153846
0.25    3   0.230769
0.5     1   0.076923
0.5     2   0.153846
0.5     3   0.230769
0.5     4   0.307692
0.5     5   0.384615
0.5     6   0.461538
```

What I am interested in is only returning the closest match as follows:

```
 Value  Id  Threshold
    0.1     1   0.076923
    0.25    3   0.230769
    0.5     6   0.461538
0.5     6   0.461538
```

Any ideas?

PS:

Found this preliminary solution:

```
select *, 
   (select top 1 Threshold 
    from #Thresholds 
    where #Thresholds.Threshold >= t.Value
    order by ABS(t.Value - #Thresholds.Threshold)  desc) as Threshold
from #DataToBeJoined t
```

Comment: It's very simple ,  row_number() over (partition by value order by threshold desc) as rn ,,,,,, where rn = 1

Comment: Thanks pls post answer. I think I also found a solution ...

Comment: Do you want the closest match either above or below?

Comment: If closest above or below then your example output and preliminary solution is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this gets what you want (at least the answers to my query match the expected).

```
SELECT Value, Id, Threshold FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() 
    OVER (PARTITION BY Value ORDER BY ABS(Value - Threshold)) as rn
  FROM #DataToBeJoined AS a
  CROSS JOIN #Thresholds AS b
) as subselect
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: but question is <= not abs  still +1

Comment: This looks promising but does not work if I add another row: SELECT 0.5 UNION so even if I enter 4 rows it returns 3 rows as a result ...

Comment: Jonny - I have adapted my solution and it seems to work for me! Using ABS(Value - Threshold) seems to do the trick. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT * 
     ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Value ORDER BY Threshold DESC) rn 
FROM  #Thresholds )
SELECT * 
FROM CTE 
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

if you insert Threshold in ascending order then can shortcut a bit

```
select #DataToBeJoined.value,  max(#Thresholds.ID), max(#Thresholds.Threshold)
  from #DataToBeJoined
  join #Thresholds 
    on #Thresholds.value <= #DataToBeJoined.Value
 group by #DataToBeJoined.value
```

if not in order

```
select * 
from
(
select #DataToBeJoined.value,  #Thresholds.ID, #Thresholds.Threshold 
     , row_number() over (partition by #DataToBeJoined.value order by #Thresholds.Threshold desc) as rn
  from #DataToBeJoined
  join #Thresholds 
    on #Thresholds.value <= #DataToBeJoined.Value
) st 
where st.rn = 1
```

Comment: sorry what do you mean by 'if you enter Threshold in ascending order' - I always thought a set based approach does not know order until you use ORDER BY

Comment: What part of "If you enter enter in ascending order" is  not clear?  Insert value is not a set based operation.  Your inserts are in ascending order.  Did you test the solution?

Comment: Yes and does not work - sorry. Even if you insert something in an order in SQL server it does mean anything IMHO so that's why I am confused by your query.

Comment: Really you think those IDENTITY are not in the order of insert?  You think by magic the max(#Thresholds.ID) lined up with the max(#Thresholds.Threshold)?

Comment: I can dig out  the book that discusses this - sorry cannot find anything to explain what I mean at the moment. IDENTITY, which I did not use anyway, is just a number but it does not mean that SQL stores it internally in an order this is what I was trying to say ... anyway this is far off subject and does not really help anyone.

Comment: Just FYI - this touches on this subject: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/05/20/without-order-by-there-is-no-default-sort-order.aspx

Comment: Really you don't use identity - [Id] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL.  You ouput ID.  If SQL does not assign identity in order then just what order does it use?

Comment: oh yeah sorry it was just an example I created as a temp table - sorry you are right. Still would argue about the order bit see link provided (-:

Comment: This has NOTHING to do with the order of a Select.  Insert is NOT a Select.  A row gets inserted and the identity is incremented and inserted in  order of the value.  Really you think  by magic the max(#Thresholds.ID) lined up with the max(#Thresholds.Threshold)?

Comment: OP down voted the correct answer when OP was not even aware he used used identity in his own question.

Comment: I apologized for that as I did not scroll up to double check how I created the simplified temp tables! What's wrong with you? I am confused why you have to be so rude with me? Your answers do not even execute never mind work - they throw errors see #Thresholds.value !!!! The value column does not even exist in the defined table.

Comment: Really you cannot adjust and use #Thresholds.Threshold.  Given you were not even aware you use identity I get that.   You don't even check your own question and I am rude.

Comment: Of course I can. I have in fact, but your answer is still wrong. I said I made a mistake regarding the identity and apologised. What else do you want?

Comment: OK you CAN fix the syntax - does it work.  Really you are not getting irony here of you discredit an answer for an incorrect column name and you don't even get your own question correct.